# C# Caminho de arquivos em outras máquinas

Tags: c#

Criei um programa que abre alguns arquivos powerpoit. Porém me deparei com a uma dúvida.
Trecho do  código:

```
private void FitaBackupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\abner\source\repos\PrjTarefas\PrjTarefas\apresentacoes\FitaBackup.ppsx");
        }
```

Percebi que mesmo que leve o arquivo "FitaBackup.ppsx" junto, a máquina que iria colocar o programa, precisava ter todo o caminho "C:\Users\abner\source\repos\" antes de chegar na pasta do programa "PrjTarefas" que iria colocar na outra máquina.

Então, tem alguma maneira para  deixar este caminho mais generalizado, evitando a pasta "source" e "repos" por exemplo? Pois a partir de "PrjTarefas" está garantido para encontrar o arquivo, o problema é o caminho anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que utilizando AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory você resolve esse problema.

Utilizei esse recurso no exemplo abaixo e deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo, porém estou com outro problema.
Meu código está assim:

        private void Zera59296929ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string caminho = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}PrjTarefas\\apresentacoes\\";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(caminho + "Zerar5929.ppsx");
        }

Retorna o caminho: C:\Users\abner\source\repos\PrjTarefas\PrjTarefas\bin\Debug\PrjTarefas\apresentacoes\

Porém o arquivo está no caminho: C:\Users\abner\source\repos\PrjTarefas\PrjTarefas\apresentacoes

Como faço para voltar 2 diretórios?

Comment: Desculpe Ramon,

Estava me confundindo com o endereço, consegui resolver o problema.

Obrigado pela ajudar!!